# importing json file to elasticsearch

Tags: json, curl, elasticsearch

I have used

`curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/<my_index_name>" -d @<absolute_path_to_my_json_file>`

Then when I tried to get the data using

`curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/<my_index_name>"`

its giving me data only for first line of my json file. (including other stuff also - settings, mappings,alias etc). 
But why is it not able to load the entire json file ? 
BTW, I am using ES 2.4.0. If I have to use bulk, what is the syntax ?

Comment: Instead of `-d` you need to use `--data-binary` when sending a file via curl.

Comment: Tried using --data-binary. It gives {"acknowledged":true}. But when I use the get command to see the data. It gives empty in second hits. Used this command - curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/<my_index_name>/_search?pretty=true"

Comment: I wanted to add one more thing here. I was able to see data when I was using ES 1.4.4. Now I changed to 2.4.0. Its not showing me data with .../_search.

Answer (score 1):

Try using these
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/`<my_index_name>`" -d `@<absolute_path_to_my_json_file>`

Answer (score 0):

`GET index` does not search actually.

You have also to run something like `GET index/_search`.

Comment: I wanted to add one more thing here. I was able to see data when I was using ES 1.4.4. Now I changed to 2.4.0. Its not showing me data with .../_search.